# Conditionally format a cell with two conditions using an AND statement

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to format a cell when the two adjacent cells match a cell in their respective rows.

I am able to conditionally format when one cell matches (J2 with column J, for example) but unable to add an ADD condition to the formula to get it to check if an additional row (K2 matches with column K).

Here is the formula that is working incorrectly.

```
=IF(EQ((VLOOKUP(J2, J:J, 1, FALSE), J2),AND(VLOOKUP(K2, K:K, 1, FALSE), K2)))
```

How can I return true on this formula IF both J2 matches a value in column J **AND** K2 matches a value in column K?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a custom formula for conditional formatting, it usually does not need `IF`. The formula should compute a boolean value (True or False), or a value that can be coerced to boolean using standard conventions (0 -> False, nonzero -> True). Formatting is applied when the formula returns True.

So, to impose two conditions, put `=AND(condition1, condition2)` in the custom formula field.